# Flagging records after meeting a condition using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.5

I need some expert opinion on the below scenario:

I have following dataframe `df1`:

```
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
|   Date1    | OrderDate  | Value | group |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
| 10/10/2020 | 10/01/2020 | hostA | grp1  |
| 10/01/2020 | 09/30/2020 | hostB | grp1  |
| Null       | 09/15/2020 | hostC | grp1  |
| 08/01/2020 | 08/30/2020 | hostD | grp1  |
| Null       | 10/01/2020 | hostP | grp2  |
| Null       | 09/28/2020 | hostQ | grp2  |
| 07/11/2020 | 08/08/2020 | hostR | grp2  |
| 07/01/2020 | 08/01/2020 | hostS | grp2  |
| NULL       | 07/01/2020 | hostL | grp2  |
| NULL       | 08/08/2020 | hostM | grp3  |
| NULL       | 08/01/2020 | hostN | grp3  |
| NULL       | 07/01/2020 | hostO | grp3  |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

Each `group` is ordered by `OrderDate` in `descending` order. Post ordering, Each `value` having `Current_date < (Date1 + 31Days) or Date1 as NULL` needs to be flagged as `valid` until `Current_date > (Date1 + 31Days)`.
Post that, every `Value` should be marked as `Invalid` irrespective of `Date1` value.

If for a `group`, all the records are `NULL`, all the `Value` should be tagged as `Valid`

My output df should look like below:

```
+------------+------------+-------+-------+---------+
|   Date1    | OrderDate  | Value | group |  Flag   |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+---------+
| 10/10/2020 | 10/01/2020 | hostA | grp1  | Valid   |
| 10/01/2020 | 09/30/2020 | hostB | grp1  | Valid   |
| Null       | 09/15/2020 | hostC | grp1  | Valid   |
| 08/01/2020 | 08/30/2020 | hostD | grp1  | Invalid |
| Null       | 10/01/2020 | hostP | grp2  | Valid   |
| Null       | 09/28/2020 | hostQ | grp2  | Valid   |
| 07/11/2020 | 08/08/2020 | hostR | grp2  | Invalid |
| 07/01/2020 | 08/01/2020 | hostS | grp2  | Invalid |
| NULL       | 07/01/2020 | hostL | grp2  | Invalid |
| NULL       | 08/08/2020 | hostM | grp3  | Valid   |
| NULL       | 08/01/2020 | hostN | grp3  | Valid   |
| NULL       | 07/01/2020 | hostO | grp3  | Valid   |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+---------+
```

**My approach:**

I created  `row_number` for each `group` after ordering by `OrderDate`.
Post that i am getting the `min(row_number)` having `Current_date > (Date1 + 31Days)` for each `group` and save it as new dataframe `dfMin`.

I then join it with  `df1` and `dfMin` on `group` and filter based on `row_number(row_number < min(row_number))`

This approach works for most cases. But when for a `group` all values of `Date1` are `NULL`, this approach fails.

Is there any other better approach to include the above scenario as well?

***Note:** I am using pretty old version of Spark- `Spark 1.5`. Also `windows` function **won't work** in my environment(Its a custom framework and there are many restrictions in place). For `row_number`, i used `zipWithIndex` method.*

Comment: really who us intrrested in 1.5 these days? i would upgrade.

Comment: i totally agree with @thebluephantom. But my organization is not.